# Accessing user data in firestore using Cloud Functions, but how do I securely send the UID/IDToken?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a http request with user's uid or token securely to my cloud functions to validate some data before posting/updating it through cloud functions.

Do I just send the token/uid in string format ? I googled it and for web development that use Bearer auth (super confused now). I am wondering what to do in swift? Is it ok to send the token/uid in string format or is there a more robust way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the token exactly as you get it from the Firebase Auth API - as a string.  You then take that same string and pass it directly to the Admin SDK to verify it as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). There's no need to add any additional security if your access to Cloud Functions is over HTTPS, which it should be.

Comment: is using the firebase functions sdk and passing it as string ok too? or use urlSession?

Comment: I don't know why it would be not-OK. Whatever you prefer.  Make sure the socket is encrypted, everything over that connection will be secure.

Comment: what the heck is a socket xd. im in csci 202.

Comment: you send user id in a URL parameter ? it means anyone that find that userID, can call that Function and get privilage of this user ( because why would your function check user ID - if not to allow/disallow access to some features)

Comment: and btw the link you provide here is not for documentation... but some sort of gym..

Comment: @gotiredofcoding I think you misunderstand what the OP is trying to do. The said token can only be obtained by an authenticated user and is validated by the Admin SDK to make sure that the user is who they say they are. It is not just passing a UID and assuming that the user is telling the truth about it.  The link to the documentation on this is correct now, showing how to pass the token in the headers of the HTTP request. This is very common practice.